# URL Fragments in Redirect for LoginRequiredMixin

Tags: django

I am using [django-braces's LoginRequiredMixin](https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.0/access.html#loginrequiredmixin) in a Django 1.6 project.  This mixin replicates Django's login_required decorator.

I have a view that uses the `LoginRequiredMixin` that has a URL like this: `/spa_home/#price_requests/68`.  If I try to hit this URL without being logged in, the mixin correctly sends me to the login page with a request like this: `/accounts/login/?next=/spa_home/#price_requests/68`.  Unfortunately, after successfully logging in, the URL hash fragment is left off and I am just redirected to `/spa_home/`.

What is the best way to fix this?  Removing hash fragments from my application would be a large effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the way the browser interprets the login URL. You want it to be intepreted like this:

```
/accounts/login/?next="/spa_home/#price_requests/68"
```

but actually, it is seen like this:

```
"/accounts/login/?next=/spa_home/"#price_requests/68
```

In other words, the hash is seen as attaching to the login URL itself, not the redirect parameter.

The way to fix this is to quote the parameter:

```
urllib.quote('/spa_home/#price_requests/68')
```

which gives you `/spa_home/%23price_requests/68`, which will be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Spot on Daniel.  Now I need to get this rolled into a push request for the way django-braces handles things in their LoginRequiredMixin.  Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel-Roseman It isn't clear to me from the linked post, at what point in the request-reponse(-redirect) cycle the hash is available server side.