# How to pass URL arguments after # sign in Django

Tags: python, django

If I send a link to a Django page which has #args in the URL, e.g.

http://localhost/someurl/?arg1=true&arg2=false#1970-01-01/2038-01-01/something_else

Then the person is not logged in - the login form appears. Unfortunately after successful login, it will redirect the person to:

http://localhost/someurl/?arg1=true&arg2=false

What I would like to keep somehow is also the #1970-01-01/2038-01-01/something_else

How can I do that in Django?

Comment: Everything after `#` doesn't get passed to the server i.e, it never leaves your browser. You can encode it on a querystring and re-create the hash using javascript `window.location.hash`. Google "fragment identifier".

Comment: I found something similar in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523060/url-fragments-in-redirect-for-loginrequiredmixin

Answer (score 0):

I would try modifying the code responsible for generating the link such that the `#` symbol is replaced by `%23` (i.e. its percent encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding ).

The final URL would be:

`http://localhost/someurl/?arg1=true&arg2=false%231970-01-01/2038-01-01/something_else`